# Adding function pointer to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, selector

I need to add some functions in a `NSMutableArray`

**Array :**

```
[_array addObject:@selector(myFunction:)];
```

**Function :**

```
- (void) myFunction:(NSString*)someParam {}
```

**Error :**

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'SEL' to parameter 'id'
```

How can I do that ? :/

The aim is to call the array functions randomly

Regards

Comment: An `@selector` isn't a Cocoa "object".

Comment: So, how can I add a function pointer to a NSMutableArray ?

Comment: Create an object that contains the selector.  You might be able to use NSValue, but I'm suspicious that an `@selector` is not a simple pointer value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only store objects in NSArray. But `SEL` is not on of those (its defined as a pointer to a structure in `<objc/objc.h>`).

In order to get your selector stored in the array, you'll have to pack it in a `NSValue` object, like so:

```
[_array addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(myFunction:)]];
```

Later, when you actually want to use your selector, you'll need to unpack it, like so:

```
SEL mySelector = [_array[0] pointerValue];

[target performSelector:mySelector];
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just call `NSStringFromSelector` and just store the string?

Comment: It would work, but won't be any easier (You'd still have to convert-to-string and the convert-from-string). I'm more inclined to use the `NSValue` solution though as it *looks* more like we are keeping the same type, just boxing it.

Comment: @jlehr: Putting a pointer into an NSvalue and getting it out are O(1). Whereas getting a selector from a string is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use blocks. For the function

```
-(void)myFunction{
}
```

Create a block by doing something like

```
void (^CallingBlock)()=^(){
    [self myFunction];
};
```

Then add to an array as normal

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:CallingBlock];
```

Then to execute the block

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a selector to an array as `SEL` isn't an object type.

If you need to store the method and parameters you could create an `NSInvocation` object and store that in your array.

Comment: Or `NSMethodSignature` if arguments aren't necessary.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: but then it won't have the name of the method